# Add custom icon in jquery ui icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, icons, customization

I have saw the question which describe how to add custom icon jquery button() but what I want is icon in jquery ui icon set as we do in

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply iconset icons to buttons like this:

```
$(function()
{
  $( "button:first" ).button({
  icons: {
   primary: "ui-icon-home"
  });
});

<button>Button with ui-icon-home</button>
```

http://jqueryui.com/button/#icons

Comment: this is the problem, I do not want to use button() I just want to use icon anywhere I want without the button

Comment: Oh. Then <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> should work?